# How to vertically align checkbox with other input controls in the form?

Tags: html, checkbox, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

My checkbox is currently aligned like this -

[image]

I want to move it to the marked/pointed location below -

[image]

I'm using Bootstrap 4. Following is my HTML -

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row form-group">
  <label class="col-md-1 col-form-label" for="director">Director</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="director" name="director" placeholder="Director">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group form-check">
  <div class="col">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="released" name="released">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="released">Released</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group">
  <label class="col-md-1 col-form-label" for="year">Year</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="year" name="year" placeholder="Year">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as

```html
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-11 offset-md-1">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="released" name="released">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="released">Released</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/L1krytub/4/

IMO, I kind of think `col-md-1` is not wide enough for your labels though.